# Datatables: consolidating rows with similar data

Tags: html, html-table, datatables

Suppose I have a table that looks like this:

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Price</th>
   <th>Product</th>
   <th>Supplier</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>

 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>$20</td>
   <td>camera</td>
   <td>Supp1</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td>$30</td>
   <td>laptop</td>
   <td>Supp1</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td>$35</td>
   <td>keyboard</td>
   <td>Supp2</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td>$40</td>
   <td>camera</td>
   <td>Supp2</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Using the Datatables library, would it be possible to consolidate the rows with the same product (camera) into one row that lists prices from both suppliers? So the result would be something like this:

```
<table>
 <thead>
  ...
 </thead>

 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>Supp1: $20<br />
       Supp2: $40</td>
   <td>camera</td>
   <td>Supp1 & Supp2</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td>$30</td>
   <td>laptop</td>
   <td>Supp1</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td>$35</td>
   <td>keyboard</td>
   <td>Supp2</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunetely no, there is no such thing in dataTables. And hard to see why someone should make a specialized plugin for that particular task. However, here is a little function that does the job for you :

```
function consolidate() {
    var product = '',
        productRows,
        products = [];

    //get a unique list of products    
    $("#example tbody tr td:nth-child(2)").each(function() {
        product = $(this).text();
        if (products.indexOf(product)<0) products.push(product);
    });

    //get all rows with a certain product
    function getProductRows(product) {
        var rows = [];
        $("#example tbody tr").each(function(index, tr) {
            if ($(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text() == product) {
                rows.push(tr);
            }
        });
        return rows;
    };

    //iterate through tbody, assemble duplicated products in a single row
    //remove duplicated rows
    $tbody = $('tbody');
    products.forEach(function(product) {
        productRows = getProductRows(product);
        if (productRows.length > 1) {
            var price,
                supplier,
                prices = '',
                suppliers = '';

            for (var i=0;i<productRows.length;i++) {
                var $row = $(productRows[i]);
                supplier = $row.find('td:eq(2)').text();
                price = $row.find('td:eq(0)').text();
                if (prices !== '') prices+='<br>';
                if (suppliers !== '') suppliers+=' & ';                
                prices+=supplier+': '+price;
                suppliers+=supplier;
                $row.remove();
            }    
            $tbody.append('<tr>'+
                          '<td>'+prices+'</td>'+
                          '<td>'+product+'</td>'+
                          '<td>'+suppliers+'</td>'+
                          '</tr>');
        }            
    });        
}
```

call the function before you initialise the datatable :

```
consolidate();

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
});
```

fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/ky9hm7c9/**
Now, you *could* wrap the above code into a dataTables plugin, but I dont think it's worth the effort.